# What is this column of 0s in a structured numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I've made a numpy structured array, but the structure is different than what I thought it would be.

```
>>> data = np.zeros(3, dtype=[('date', 'datetime64[ms],i4'), ('price', np.float32)])

>>> data
array([(('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.),    
       (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.), 
       (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.)], 
       dtype=[('date', [('f0', '<M8[ms]'), ('f1', '<i4')]), ('price', '<f4')])
```

I wonder what the 0 values next to date column are. Even when I put a new value in the column, I have to clarify it as well, which I don't see why.

`data[0][0] = (np.datetime64('2017-10-24 01:00:07.870000'), 0)` --> works

`data[0][0] = np.datetime64('2017-10-24 01:00:07.870000')` --> gets the wrong value

```
array([(('49782-03-08T18:11:10.000', 0),  0.),
     (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.),
     (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.)],
     dtype=[('date', [('f0', '<M8[ms]'), ('f1', '<i4')]), ('price', '<f4')])
```

Could anyone explain to me what they are for? And I'd like to know how I can select a column like `data[:,0]` in a structured array.

Comment: You should index fields by name, `data['price']`, `data['date']['f0']` etc

Comment: What's the purpose of the 'i4' in your creation expression?

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for your help! I thought i4 was part of datetime option. Do you happen to know how to initialize default values when making a structured array, for example with NaT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have three levels nested here :

```
In [644]: data[0]
Out[644]: (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.)

In [645]: data[0][0]
Out[645]: ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0)

In [646]: data[0][0][0]
Out[646]: numpy.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000')
```

You can set it by :

```
In [647]: data[0][0][0]=datetime64('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Could you tell me why it's necessary and how I can make a structured array without it? I don't see which part of `data = np.zeros(3, dtype=[('date', 'datetime64[ms],i4'), ('price', np.float32)])` made it.

Comment: I think the i4 has no sense here. just try `np.zeros(3, dtype=[('date', 'datetime64[ms]), ('price', np.float32)])` , it will behave like you think. type help(numpy.dtype) for more explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing and setting fields by name:

```
In [16]: data = np.zeros(3, dtype=[('date', 'datetime64[ms],i4'), ('price', np.f
    ...: loat32)])
In [17]: data
Out[17]: 
array([(('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.),
       (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.),
       (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 0),  0.)],
      dtype=[('date', [('f0', '<M8[ms]'), ('f1', '<i4')]), ('price', '<f4')])
In [18]: data['price']=[1,3,4]
In [19]: data['date']['f1']=12
In [21]: data
Out[21]: 
array([(('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 12),  1.),
       (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 12),  3.),
       (('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000', 12),  4.)],
      dtype=[('date', [('f0', '<M8[ms]'), ('f1', '<i4')]), ('price', '<f4')])
```

Accessing a field of a particular record (element):

```
In [22]: data['price'][0]
Out[22]: 1.0
In [23]: data['price'][[1,2]]
Out[23]: array([ 3.,  4.], dtype=float32)
```

But let's drop the useless `i4` field

```
In [29]: data = np.zeros(3, dtype=[('date', 'datetime64[ms]'), ('price', np.float32)])
In [30]: data
Out[30]: 
array([('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000',  0.), ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000',  0.),
       ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.000',  0.)],
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[ms]'), ('price', '<f4')])
```

Now we can assign values to the `date` field

```
In [31]: data['date']=[1,2,3]     # ms
In [32]: data
Out[32]: 
array([('1970-01-01T00:00:00.001',  0.), ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.002',  0.),
       ('1970-01-01T00:00:00.003',  0.)],
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[ms]'), ('price', '<f4')])

In [33]: data['date']=np.array([1,2,3],dtype='datetime64[Y]') # years
In [34]: data
Out[34]: 
array([('1971-01-01T00:00:00.000',  0.), ('1972-01-01T00:00:00.000',  0.),
       ('1973-01-01T00:00:00.000',  0.)],
      dtype=[('date', '<M8[ms]'), ('price', '<f4')])
```

A single date:

```
In [35]: data['date'][2] = np.array('2017-10-31', 'datetime64[D]')
In [36]: data[2]
Out[36]: ('2017-10-31T00:00:00.000',  0.)
```